# How to take a reference from maven project to spring project?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, classpath

I have a 2 project. One of them is maven, other one is spring project. I obtain jar file from maven project and give reference to spring project. When I call some classes and methods in compile time, it's ok. But when I started tomcat server I got a error that is ***"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"*** and ***"NoClassDefFoundError"***. Application does not see classes on run time.

I supposed that this error is occured cause of tomcats run time classpaths. I must add missing classes to classpaths. But how to do that ? How to handle this problem ?

IDE: Eclipse

Tomcat version: 9

Thanks for your answers. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How do you "give reference to spring project"? How do you publish to tomcat? Is your spring project also a maven project?

Comment: Yes spring project is a maven project. I right click to spring project and go to java buith path then Libraries. And ı clicked "add jar". I have putted maven jar file to WEB-INF/lib before, and I select this path. I also selected this jar on "Order and Export" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create jar file of your maven project and put into `WEB-INF > lib` of Spring project and and jar file into built path and rebuild the Spring project and run it from tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the jar file to Deployment Assembly. Right click on your project, click Properties, Deployment Assembly, Add your jar file and run the project on tomcat.